Getting warning of "format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]" when Im pretty sure my code is correct?
So I am new to coding and am teaching myself C. Today I was trying to write a simple program using scanf() but I'm not getting the output I expect. Whatever number I type it seems like scanf() either isn't storing the value, or is returning the address of the value.
My code is:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1;
    printf("Please enter a number: \n");
    scanf("%i", &num1);
    printf("You have entered: %i!", &num1);
    return 0;
}

And the output I'm getting is:
Please enter a number: 
4
You have entered: 1803728744!%

I have double and triple checked my code against other sample pieces, I have changed the data type to float, decimal, etc. and I can't figure out why its not printing the number I type, and instead printing a long number with !% at the end.

The part about !% at the end is interesting. Are you using some unusual platform?

The %i specifier in printf needs an int, not a pointer to int. You should usually use %d instead of %i for printing ints.

@anatolyg: it is a classic side effect of the missing newline... see my answer.

A side note: you should check the return value from scanf - it returns the number of assigned fields (should be 1 in your case).

Your scanf is fine; it is only your printf that is wrong. (If you have a debugger you should try using it; it would show you this.) You passed &num1 to correspond to a %i specifier. %i takes a value of type int, but &num1 is the address of a local int variable; this is exactly what the compiler warning told you (it expected int but you passed int*). Depending on the system you run on and the compiler you use, the address of a local variable is usually a large number, and it always is a number completely different from the variable's contents.

This is #1 on the list of 14 weird things about scanf that nobody ever teaches you.  (You might be interested in the other 13, too.)

"I have double and triple checked my code against other sample pieces" Quadruple check it!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend -Wall -Wextra as a minimum; consider also -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds for identifying some other common mistakes.

@anatolyg - probably just the shell prompt after the program exited without writing a complete line of output.

There are multiple issues:

You get the warning because you pass the address of num1 instead of its value. Remove the & to fix this. &num1 is a pointer to the num1 variable: scanf() needs to receive pointers to destination variables in order to store the converted values into them, whereas printf only needs the values to compute their representation according to the format specifications.

The output ends with !% because you do not output a newline after You have entered: %i! and your shell prompt is % .  Add a \n at the end of the string.

You should always test the return value of scanf() to detect invalid or missing input and avoid undefined behavior accessing the variables that won't have been read by scanf().  scanf returns the number of conversions assigned, 1 in your case if the characters typed by the user represent an integer, or EOF if no such conversions could be performed before reaching the end of file.

%i behaves the same as %d in printf, but the latter is usually preferred.  %i in scanf() accepts integers expressed in decimal, octal, hexadecimal (and binary since C23) using the appropriate prefix. Use %d for clarity.


Here is a modified version:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1;
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    if (scanf("%i", &num1) == 1) {
        printf("You have entered: %d!\n", num1);
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
}


It may be a good idea to say why printf needs num1 instead of &num1 while scanf is the other way around. When a student makes this mistake, it suggests the code is some incantation they are writing without understanding, and hence they copied things between scanf and printf. They should be given the appropriate ideas: printf takes a value, formats it, and prints it, so all it needs is the value, num1. scanf is going to change a variable, so it needs to know where the variable is, &num1.

@EricPostpischil: good point, answer amended.

@truballin: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

printf requires int value not pointer: printf("You have entered: %i!", num1);
